# ElasticSearch Query_String search forward slash excaping

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write a query for this filepath:

`C:/This/Is/My/File.txt`

like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "default_field": "filePath",
           "query": "C:This\\/Is\\/My\\/File.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

However it is giving me an error saying:

> SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query]

So I'm assuming it has something to do with the escaping but it seems to be correct.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Why do you want to use query_string for this , use term query

Comment: I'm allowing users to input using the query_string formatting for searching...I'll just have to specify in my documentation that to escape a / they have to use \/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"query": {
        "query_string": {
           "default_field": "filePath",
           "query": "C\\:\\/NewRevelation\\/PlexMaster\\/Cloud.CDN\\/Content\\/xslt\\/Modules\\/Purchasing\\/Shared\\/Specifications.xslt"
        }
    }
```

Since it's going to need to see / after parsing through the input string you need the extra \